Selenium screenshot of table with custom font
I have the following Python code for loading the given page in selenium and taking a screenshot of the table.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from PIL import Image
import io
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--force-device-scale-factor=1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

path = os.path.abspath("table_minimal.html")
driver.get(f"file://{path}")
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))
png = table.screenshot_as_png
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(png))
im.save("table.png")
driver.quit()

Here is the table_minimal.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td>Text in the table</td></tr></tbody></table>
</body>
</html>

The above produces this image:

If I remove the --headless flag then I get this instead:

So first one does not use the custom font, the second does but detects incorrect table width. Is there some settings I am missing to make this work correctly? Preferably in headless mode, but now I am curious why it does not work in normal mode as well...

Note: Changed the font to Matemasie to make it stand out more in the screenshot.

The issue is caused by the screenshot being taken before the custom font has loaded.
There are some ways to wait for that to finish before continuing, eg:

Selenium ChromeDriver "get" doesn't reliably load @import fonts

time.sleep(2) also works on such a simple DOM :)

Adding that to the code, and using table.screenshot() to take the screenshot gives us:
path = os.path.abspath("table_minimal.html")
driver.get(f"file://{path}")

while True:
    script = '''return document.fonts.status;'''
    loaded = driver.execute_script(script)
    if loaded == 'loaded':
        break
    time.sleep(.5)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))
table.screenshot('./test3.png')

driver.quit()

Gives the expected result, with both --headless and without:


Ahh I get it, the screenshot is taken before the font loads, please see my edit with a way to wait for all the custom font's to load properly @Sil

Awesome, works in both modes correctly! Thank you. Also nice font :)

Hehe, yea I kinda like it ;) Glad it's working, kinda weird there is no build in nicer way to wait for this, but seems fine. +1 for the nice question, with perfect reproducible issue!
